# iPhone: UIImage background color appears different from UIView background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiimage

I have an image with a colored background. I put it in a larger view, and change the view's background color in the storyboard so it matches the image's background.

Yet, even though they are set to be the same color (using the HTML code), the View's background color appears (in simulator) significantly darker than the UIImage's background.

Any idea on why and how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: why dont you set imageview as background (one pixel image having color which you need)

Comment: I could but it's a hassle.
There is no code to post, I am only using the storyboard.

Comment: color may differ as per device and device brightness. its better to use image

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to do this through the UI and storyboard because the color selection process is not exact in the UI but it is very easy to do in code. Use a color picker and get the numeric value of the color of your image and then set the background to match e.g.

```
 super.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.314, green: 0.675, blue: 0.282, alpha: 1.00)
```